# 13 " to 14" rims on lightweight 3x5ft trailer

Tags: wheels, trailer

Can I change my 13" rims on my trailer to 14" rims with same stud pattern without having to change axel or wheel bearings  Trailer is lightweight 3 x 5 ft Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As long as there is clearance of  physical parts (tire doesn't rub on something) there should be no issues moving to a larger diameter wheel.